# Is there anyway of reliably inferring facebook "like button" property og:description within the body?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know of course that I can not put a meta tag into the body but I don't want to have to completely rewrite my CMS in order to allow me to include a content specific tag in the header of every single page. I was wondering whether there is any foolproof way of inferring the description of the page through how you structure your page/ code.

At the moment facebook tends to use some short text from an small rss feed as a description instead of the bulk of my article. I don't know how facebook decides what the description is for a page which doesn't use the og:description meta tags. Im hoping if I can set the page up so that facebook works it out itself.

[Example Article](http://www.80threadingscouts.org.uk/index.php/exec/25-reading-half-marathon) [What facebook sees](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.80threadingscouts.org.uk%2Findex.php%2Fexec%2F25-reading-half-marathon)